Finding link redirections with Python
I have a dataframe with two rows, both correspond to apartment offers in a real estate website. The first offer has an invalid link, since the data was downloaded a long time ago and it was withdrawn; while the second one has a valid link.
invalid=df.loc[0, "Link"]
valid=df.loc[1, "Link"]

The valid link is this: https://www.habitaclia.com/comprar-piso-oportunidad_grande_de_4_habitaciones_con_balcon_en_plena_ra_el_clot-barcelona-i45207000000035.htm?pag=1001&f=&geo=c&from=list&lo=55; and the invalid link is this: https://www.habitaclia.com/comprar-piso-poblenou_la_vila_olimpica_del_poblenou-barcelona-i3118004333089.htm?pag=413&f=&geo=c&from=list&lo=55. As you can notice, the invalid link, when trying to open it, redirects to https://www.habitaclia.com/viviendas-barcelona.htm?state=1; while the valid link, when trying to open it, stays at the same address.
I want to create a Python script that allows me to enter the links and see if they are still valid or not. I can check this because the invalid ones redirect to another address.
I have tried to do it with this code:
response = requests.head(invalid, allow_redirects=True)
url_redirected = response.url
print(url_redirected)

But I get this link: https://www.habitaclia.com/comprar-piso-poblenou_la_vila_olimpica_del_poblenou-barcelona-i3118004333089.htm?pag=413&f=&geo=c&from=list&lo=55, when it should be this: https://www.habitaclia.com/viviendas-barcelona.htm?state=1.

Voted to reopen because your issue is related to the fact that the website is returning a 403 if you don't include a valid user agent. Try requests.head(invalid, headers={'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/124.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'}).

there are 3 types of redirection: (1) HTTP can send header 3xx with new URL, (2) HTML may have special <meta> with new URL, (3) JavaScript may replace document.url or similar object and browser will reload it. Using requests you can catch method (1) and (2) and you can check response.history to see it. But for method (3) you may need to get response.text and check if there is some JavaScript with document.url or similar element, or you may have to use Selenium  to control real web browser which can run JavaScript.
